# How to sort map using comparator with reflection in original map?

Tags: c++, stl, c++17, comparator, multimap

How to sort the multimap using comparator.
It should be reflected in the multimap container

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

// Comparator function to sort pairs
// according to second value
bool cmp(pair<string, int>& a,
        pair<string, int>& b)
{
    return a.second < b.second;
}

// Function to sort the map according
// to value in a (key-value) pairs
void sort(multimap<string, int>& M)
{

    // Declare vector of pairs
    vector<pair<string, int> > A;

    // Copy key-value pair from Map
    // to vector of pairs
    for (auto& it : M) {
        A.push_back(it);
    }

    // Sort using comparator function
    sort(A.begin(), A.end(), cmp);

    // Print the sorted value
    for (auto& it : A) {

        cout << it.first << ' '
            << it.second << endl;
    }
}

// Driver Code
int main()
{

    // Declare Map
    multimap<string, int> M;

    // Given Map
    M = { { "GfG", 3 },
        { "To", 2 },
        { "Welcome", 1 } };

    // Function Call
    sort(M);
  cout<<"\n";
  for(auto i:M)
  {
    cout<<i.first<<" "<<i.second<<endl;
  }
  
  return 0;
}
```

This is code I got from Geekforgeeks!
I totally understood the concept but I need to know how to sort the map itself if the map is multimap.?

**OUTPUT**

Welcome 1 
To 2 
GfG 3 

GfG 3
To 2
Welcome 1

Comment: If you want the map to be ordered in a specific way, why don'y you use the ordering function for the map itself?

Comment: And generally, don't use code from so-called "competition" or "online judge" sites to learn programming and least of all good habits. Such sites are *not* learning or teaching resources, and the examples and submissions tend to use bad habits, bad code, and often also invalid code. Case in point: [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) and [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: The only way to sort a `multimap` is a create a new one with a different compare function.  Also your `void sort(multimap<string, int>& M)` does not make any changes to `M`.

Comment: Oh, and there's nothing in the code or the use of the map that necessitate a `std::multimap` over a plain `std::map`. To be honest I don't think ordering on the data will even work well with a multimap where the ordering function is used to handle the duplicate *keys*.

Comment: So there is no way I can be ordering map or multimap with values???

Comment: No, there is not. `std::map` and `std::muplimap` are sorted by key; this is the fundamental property of these data structures. If you need a different property, use a different data structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically the answer has been given in the comments already. I will summarize again and show an alternative.

The background is that we often want to use the properties of an ***associative*** container, but later sort it by its ***value*** and not by the ***key***.

The ***unsorted associative*** containers, like `std::unsorted_set`, `std::unordered_map` , `std::unordered_multiset` and `std::unordered_multimap` cannot be ordered, as their names say. They are using a ***hash*** algorithm to store and retrieve their values.

Please read also in the [CPP Reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) about STL container.

And, if we look at the ***sorted associative*** container, we see that the `std::set` and the `std::multiset` do not work with key value pairs and the other two, the `std::map` and `std::multimap` have a ***key*** and ***value*** but are always sorted by their ***key***.

But as said, we often want to have the advantages of an ***Associative container*** with a ***key - value*** pair and later some sorted-by-the-value data.

This can only be acieved by using 2 container having the needed property. In your above example the data is copied into a `std::vector` and then sorted. This mechanism can be used always, with any sortable container, by adding a `std::pair` of ***key*** and ***value*** to a container. So:

```
using Pair = std::pair<std::string, int>;
using Conatiner = std::vector<Pair>;
```

An often needed use case is counting something. For example, counting the letters in a string. This can be really easily achieved with a `std::map` or `std::unordered_map` and the sorted by the ***value*** using a 2nd container. Please see some example code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <set>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <type_traits>

// ------------------------------------------------------------
// Create aliases. Save typing work and make code more readable
using Pair = std::pair<char, unsigned int>;

// Standard approach for counter
using Counter = std::unordered_map<Pair::first_type, Pair::second_type>;

// Sorted values will be stored in a multiset, because their may be double ranks
struct Comp { bool operator ()(const Pair& p1, const Pair& p2) const { return (p1.second == p2.second) ? p1.first<p2.first : p1.second>p2.second; } };
using Rank = std::multiset<Pair, Comp>;
// ------------------------------------------------------------

// Function to get the rank of letters in a string
Rank getRank(const std::string& str) {

    Counter counter;
    for (const char c : str) counter[c]++;

    return { counter.begin(), counter.end() };
}

// Test / Driver Code
int main() {

    if (std::string userString{}; std::getline(std::cin, userString))

    for (const auto& [letter, count] : getRank(userString))
        std::cout << (int)letter << ' ' << count << ' ';
}
```

So, we use the property of the `std::unordred map` as a fast associative container, not sorted by the key, in combination with a `std::multiset` which will act as a "sorter".

---

Or, you can take a `std::multiset` from the beginning. Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <set>

// ------------------------------------------------------------
// Create aliases. Save typing work and make code more readable
using Pair = std::pair <std::string, int> ;

// Sorted values will be stored in a multiset
struct Comp { bool operator ()(const Pair& p1, const Pair& p2) const { return (p1.second == p2.second) ? p1.first<p2.first : p1.second<p2.second; } };
using Sorted = std::multiset<Pair, Comp>;
// ------------------------------------------------------------

// Driver Code
int main()
{
    Sorted data {  { "GfG", 3 }, { "To", 2 },  { "Welcome", 1 } };

    for (const auto& [key, value] : data)
        std::cout << key << '\t' << value << '\n';
}
```

Depends of course all on what you want to achieve . . .